# Update trigger column based on date in ddmmyyy format in Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, triggers

I have created a trigger based on which I want to assign column with some value.

For example: I have a column name `BILL_CALCULATED_DATE` with value `19-10-21` which is in `dd-mm-yy` format. I want to extract mm and if it is `10` then I want to assign it as `October`

Below is my trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_UPD_GTL_BILL
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON IPFEE_MST_INSRT_GTL
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 :new.BILL_CALCULATED_DATE := case :NEW.UPLOADED_MONTH
                     when '01' then 'January'
                     when '02' then 'February'
                     when '03' then 'March'
                     when '04' then 'April'
                     when '05' then 'May'
                     when '06' then 'June'
                     when '07' then 'July'
                     when '08' then 'August'
                     when '09' then 'September'
                     when '10' then 'October'
                     when '11' then 'November'
                     when '12' then 'December'
end;
end;
```

But the problem is, before assigning month in the trigger I want to extract the month. How should I achieve it ?

Comment: What is the data type of the `BILL_CALCULATED_DATE` column?

Comment: Posting tips: (1) please only use the quote block for quotes, and not as a general paragraph highlighter. (2) please refrain from adding begging, pleading, or phrases that carry a meaning of emotional coercion. People are generally here in their free time, and do not need to be nagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `BILL_CALCULATED_DATE` column is of the `DATE` data type and you want the `UPLOADED_MONTH` column to be the name of the month corresponding to `BILL_CALCULATED_DATE`'s month then:

Do not use a trigger; use a virtual column then the column values will always be synchronised.

Either create the table using:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IPFEE_MST_INSRT_GTL(
  BILL_CALCULATED_DATE DATE,
  UPLOADED_MONTH      VARCHAR2(9)
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      CAST(
        TO_CHAR(BILL_CALCULATED_DATE, 'fmMonth', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
        AS VARCHAR2(9)
      )
    )
);
```

Or modify the existing table to drop the non-virtual column and add a virtual column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE IPFEE_MST_INSRT_GTL DROP COLUMN UPLOADED_MONTH;

ALTER TABLE IPFEE_MST_INSRT_GTL
  ADD UPLOADED_MONTH VARCHAR2(9)
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      CAST(
        TO_CHAR(BILL_CALCULATED_DATE, 'fmMonth', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
        AS VARCHAR2(9)
      )
    );
```

If you must use a trigger and a real column then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_UPD_GTL_BILL
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON IPFEE_MST_INSRT_GTL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.UPLOADED_MONTH := TO_CHAR(
                           :new.BILL_CALCULATED_DATE,
                           'fmMonth',
                           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
                         );
END;
/
```

---

If your `BILL_CALCULATED_DATE` column is a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` data type then:

1. Change that column to a `DATE`.
2. If you cannot change it to a `DATE` then go and talk to someone who can change it to a `DATE`.
3. If you really, really cannot change it to a `DATE` then spend time despairing about the inability to follow best practice, try to convince people who may have the ability to do something about it that you should change things and then replace `BILL_CALCULATED_DATE` with `TO_DATE(BILL_CALCULATED_DATE, 'DD-MM-YY')` or `:new.BILL_CALCULATED_DATE` with `TO_DATE(:new.BILL_CALCULATED_DATE, 'DD-MM-YY')` in the snippets above.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=67bc6e763830000bac98b4e94d1e8725)*

Comment: Thanks MT0. my `BILL_CALCULATED_DATE` is DATE datatype only

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding your column is not in date format. First convert this into date and then use EXTRACT function -

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE(BILL_CALCULATED_DATE, 'dd-mm-yy'))
  FROM IPFEE_MST_INSRT_GTL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM SYSDATE) from dual
```

Comment: getting error as `ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source` from actual code `SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM BILL_CALCULATED_DATE) from IPFEE_MST_INSRT_GTL;`